# Can I create an <a> tag to open the Inspect Element panel?

Tags: html, element, inspect

Just wondering if this can be done simply in html. If so, how?

```
<a href="inspectElement">Check out my code!</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Safari / Google Chrome developer tools programmatically from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660325/open-safari-google-chrome-developer-tools-programmatically-from-javascript). Interesting: [It might work for browser add ons.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528437/how-do-i-programatically-open-the-developer-tools-console-in-a-firefox-addon)

Answer (score 0):

Inspect Element is part of the browser, so no.